# What is the difference between reversing a list in place and reversing using slicing in python?

Tags: python, list, slice

```
s[:] = s[::-1]
```

versus

```
s = s[::-1]
```

Please explain the difference between achieving the result using the above methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first mutates the original list itself. The second creates a new list, and assigns it back to the variable.

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]
>>> id(s)
2186036088200        # original id
>>> s[:] = s[::-1]
>>> id(s)
2186036088200        # still same id
>>> s = s[::-1]
>>> id(s)
2186036085000        # new id, because new list was created
```

The first method is called "slice assignment".